# How to represent each data entry with a pie chart of its values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have the following simple data set `data`.

```
ID,A,B,C,D
a,0,1,0,0
b,1,1,1,0
c,0,0,1,1
```

It is quite easy to create a circle for every data entry with the standard update pattern:

```
var course = d3.selectAll(".course")
  .data(data, d => d.ID);

course.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("class", "course");

course.exit().remove();
```

Now I would like to replace the circles with small pie charts, using the information in the columns. The pie chart should have a piece for every 1. For example, `b` should be represented by a 3-pieced pie chart (one for `A`, `B` and `C` respectively). Here is what I have already tried:

```
var course = d3.selectAll(".course")
  .data(data, d => d.ID);

course.enter()
  .each(function (c) {
    var values = d3.values(c)
      .splice(2, 5);

    var pie = d3.pie()(values);

    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(10);

    d3.select(this)
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc(pie));
  }
```

There are no errors to be seen in the console, but no pie charts either... The computed angles in `pie` seem fine, though. What did I do wrong? I discovered [Pie Multiples](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111), but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Hard to say exactly, it looks about right, are the paths getting appended at all?

Comment: @JoshRumbut Yes, they are appended, but they all have value `d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick and very dirty update to the [Pie Multiples block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111) to show how it might be done. Does this help?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELMgaP

```js
var data = [{
    ID: 'a',
    A: 2,
    B: 1,
    C: 1
  },
  {
    ID: 'b',
    A: 1,
    B: 1,
    C: 7
  },
];

// Define the margin, radius, and color scale. The color scale will be
// assigned by index.
var m = 10,
  r = 100,
  z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

// Insert an svg element (with margin) for each row in our dataset. A child g
// element translates the origin to the pie center.
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
  .data(data, d => d.ID)
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", (r + m) * 2)
  .attr("height", (r + m) * 2)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + m) + "," + (r + m) + ")");

// The data for each svg element is a row of numbers (an array). We pass that to
// d3.pie to compute the angles for each arc. These start and end angles
// are passed to d3.arc to draw arcs! 
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data((d, i) => d3.pie()(d3.values(data[i]).splice(1, 5)))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", d => d3.arc().innerRadius(r / 2).outerRadius(r)(d))
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  })
  .style('stroke', 'black');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

My guess is your code is also very close to working but without seeing the values of all the variables I'm not sure what the little bug is (although I am pretty sure it is a little bug).

Comment: I will have a look at this tomorrow. For now, I can confirm is that all values are simply 0 or 1 (I checked them all in the console).

Comment: @Jeroen I wasn't sure of the semantics of your data, exactly what was supposed to happen in case of a 0 or 1, so I just put in different data to make the demo more interesting.